# how to find duplicate element with multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have scenario where in a table contains 2 columns.
product and sub like

```
Sno    Product  Sub
1      pr1      sub1 
2      pr1      sub1 
3      pr2      sub1 
4      pr2      sub1 
5      pr3      sub2
6      pr4      sub3
7      pr5      sub3
8      pr6      sub4
9      pr6      sub4
```

I want to find element which have col **sub** assigned to col **product** more than 1.But diff product not same.

so my result will be **sub1**,**sub3**
expected result will be distinct :

```
    Sub
 1  sub1
 2  sub3
```

I tried using group by on product and sub something like :

```
SELECT
    product,
    sub,
    COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY
    product,
    sub
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

but this is not correct for the given scenario .
Need your advice on this.

Comment: You have to remove `sub` field from both the `select` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result as a formatted table!

Comment: sure i ll make modification

Comment: @jarlh i am done with modification.

Comment: Add (8, pr5, sub4) too, and adjust the result if required.

Comment: Whats the problem with using this ?
SELECT SUB FroM table1
GROUP BY  SUB
HAVING COUNt(*)>1;

This will give you the expected results.

Comment: @JayeshMulwani, depends on what OP wants... If same sub appears twice for a prduct, is it counted once or twice?

Comment: @jarlh , As per my understanding because of this comment in the question , "so my result will be sub1,sub3 expected result will be distinct :" , even if the same sub is mapped twice for a product even then the user wants it once , Please correct me if i am wrong here

Comment: @JayeshMulwani, I don't know, it's not quite clear... That's why proper sample data is so important.

Comment: @JayeshMulwani if same sub appears for same product multiple .it will not be counted. in your current query it is selecting for 'sub4' .which is not correct as per my condition. can you please relook into it.

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar , Ok clear now.
How about ? 

**`SELECT SUB FroM table1
GROUP BY  SUB
HAVING COUNt(DIStINCT PrODUCT)>1;`**

Comment: yes definately that would work .@JayeshMulwani that would work but i already accepted answer.Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate per `sub and use`HAVING` to only get those with multiple products:

```
select sub
from table1
group by sub
having min(product) <> max(product);
```

or

```
select sub
from table1
group by sub
having count(distinct product) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the sample data provided in question, it seems that you are looking for all distinct rows from column `Sub` having more than one `product`. You can achieve this using below query.

```
select a.sub from (
select distinct sub, product from table1
    ) a
group by a.sub  
having count(*) > 1
```

**Result:**

```
    SUB
--------    
1   sub1
2   sub3
```

You can check demo **[here](http://rextester.com/IVD22896)**

Comment: awesome zarruq.

Comment: Thanks everyone for who take time suggest on th is.

Comment: That's quite a complicated way to count distinct values. Simply use `COUNT(DISTINCT product)` instead. `count(sub)` is even confusing in your query and makes it less readable; it should be `count(*)` instead, because you are counting records. `count(sub)` suggestst that there can be null subs you want to exclude from the count. Don't do that.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Ah my bad. Thanks for the `count(*)` suggestion. And the reason for the complication is that result required that all distinct rows from `sub` be returned which has more than one `products` associated with it given that rows can also be repeated, so a distinct is used first to remove duplicate rows and then `group by` on top of that.

Comment: Yes, but `COUNT` accepts a `DISTINCT` keyword, so we don't need any subquery at all. Please see my answer on this.

Comment: @thorstenkettner: Oh, i see. Thats awsome.. +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
SELECT sub FROM table1 
GROUP BY sub
HAVING COUNT(sub) > 1
```

Comment: Error _Set function not specified in a SELECT clause or HAVING clause_.

Comment: sorry i don't see sub field was varchar type

Comment: @ No jackques it is selecting row with "sub4" which is assigned to same product.not different product.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.product,t1.sub,t1.Count 
FROM
  (SELECT product,sub,DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition By product ORDER BY Sub) Count 
   FROM table1
   ) t1
WHERE t1.Count=2 
-- = 2 Means product Repeated more than 1
```

Comment: You cannot have window functions in the `WHERE` clause. And anyway, your approach is very complicated for the small task given.